# C# WPF. How to add Ellipces dynamically into canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to add some ellipces with random positions into my canvas, but i can see them on my canvas. Progmab is compilling quite saccesfull. Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FirefliesCount; ++i)
            {
                Firefly CurrentFirefly = new Firefly();
                CurrentFirefly.Speed = Randomer.Next(1, 3);
                CurrentFirefly.Body = new Ellipse();
                CurrentFirefly.Body.Margin = new Thickness(Randomer.Next(10, (int)MainCanvas.Width - 10),
                                                           Randomer.Next(10, (int)MainCanvas.Height - 10),
                                                           0, 0);
                CurrentFirefly.Body.Fill = Brushes.Black;
                CurrentFirefly.Body.Height = MainCanvas.Height / 4;
                CurrentFirefly.Body.Width = 1.5 * CurrentFirefly.Body.Height;
                MainCanvas.Children.Add(CurrentFirefly.Body);
            }
```

And Fireflie class:

```
class Firefly
{
    public Ellipse Body { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did not set the `Width` and `Height` properties of your `MainCanvas`; then they have the value `NaN` and therefore you will not see the ellipses.
My suggestion is to use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` instead and to delay the adding of the ellipses until the canvas is loaded. Here is an example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainCanvas.Loaded += MainCanvas_Loaded;
    }

    void MainCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        const int FirefliesCount = 100;
        Random Randomer = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < FirefliesCount; ++i)
        {
            Firefly CurrentFirefly = new Firefly();
            CurrentFirefly.Speed = Randomer.Next(1, 3);
            CurrentFirefly.Body = new Ellipse();
            CurrentFirefly.Body.Margin = new Thickness(Randomer.Next(10, (int)MainCanvas.ActualWidth - 10),
                                                       Randomer.Next(10, (int)MainCanvas.ActualHeight - 10),
                                                       0, 0);
            CurrentFirefly.Body.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            CurrentFirefly.Body.Height = MainCanvas.ActualHeight / 4;
            CurrentFirefly.Body.Width = 1.5 * CurrentFirefly.Body.Height;
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(CurrentFirefly.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding xaml file looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"/>
</Window>
```